# What is the difference with/without curly brackets?

Tags: javascript

I saw a source code and noticed there was an "additional" curly brackets around `a.name` as below, although the common case I usually see is without curly bracket.
I'm wondering this works differently in some specific cases, which I tried and came out the same though, or some sort of convention. Does anybody know the difference?

With curly bracket

```js
array.forEach((item, index) => {
  let a = {
    id: index;
  };

  {
    a.name = 'test';
  }
}
```

Without curly bracket

```js
array.forEach((item, index) => {
  let a = {
    id: index;
  };
  
  a.name = 'test';
}
```

Comment: They're the same. May be the author tried to add some object there, and changed his mind later

Comment: WIth curly brackets is programmatically wrong. You can't just put an object like that. Maybe the author just tried testing.

Comment: It’s an unlabelled block afaik.

Comment: I wanted to say it's an anonymous scope but neither "js anonymous scope" nor "js unlabelled block" appear on google results. I'm sure there must be some formal name. Maybe it's just seldom considered since it's less relevant in langages after C(where all variables needed to be declared at top of the scope, so new scopes let you define new variables half way through the function).

Comment: @Dmitry https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: ah so "block statement".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both examples are the same in this case, however, it has two uses in other cases.

One use is to force the scope of a variable declared with `let`. `let` variables are "block scoped", and if you declare them inside a "block" like this, then they will be scoped to that block. For example:

```
let cookies = "Cookies are nice";

console.log(cookies);// "Cookies are nice"
```

but

```
{
    let cookies = "Cookies are nice";
}

console.log(cookies);// Reference error
```

The other use for them is simply to force auto-indenting to have an extra indent in your IDE... For example, most IDEs do not auto-indent PHP code, and some programmers will chose to use these blocks to fake out the IDE into auto-indenting.

For example:

```
<?php

//the code in here won't be auto-indented

?>
```

but

```
<?php
{
    //if I do this, then it will be auto-indented.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I think it might be for IDE in my case to indent :)